# codenameone floating action button - Change Text Foreground Color

Tags: text, colors, themes, codenameone

I can't change the gray color of the FloatingActionButton Text, i've change all the attributes of the FloatingActionButton theme... and the text is still gray.

Please can some home help me? with an example perhaps.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post (as text using the `{}` widget`) a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The icon is created from the material font when the button is created and it derives the color from the UIID of the FAB.

Since it's now an icon it's no longer affected by changes you make to the color etc. We might change that in the future.

If you create a style either in the designer or through CSS you can apply it using `setUIID()` and that should just create a new icon with your new foreground color.

Answer (score 1):

Shai,

I've found the answer: I must modify FloatingActionText attribute.
Thanks a lot

Ramon Gacia